# Retrieving 50 results from google using java

Tags: java

I am having difficulties in retrieving 50 results from google.

I'm using this:

```
public static List Retrieve(String entry){
    List entryList = new ArrayList();

      try {  
             // string new entry is making the keywords into query that can be known by google
             String newEntry = (java.net.URLEncoder.encode(entry, "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));

             // inputing the keywords to google search engine
             URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.id/search?q=" + newEntry + "&hl=en&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=");  
             // makking connection to the internet
             URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();  
             urlConn.setUseCaches(false);  
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729)");  

             // getting the input stream of page html into bufferedreader
             BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));  
             String line;  
             StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();  

       // getting the input stream of html into stringbuffer       
       while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {  
        buffer.append(line);  
       }  

       // finding the links
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(GOOGLE);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(buffer.toString().toLowerCase());
        while (m.find()) {
            String link = m.group(0);
            // putting the links of google search into list
            entryList.add(link);
        }
           } catch (Exception e) {  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());  
           } 

    return entryList;
}
```

But it only shows only ten results.

Comment: How do you retrieve your data?

Comment: Well, I can get millions of results by entering a search term and browsing through them ... seriously, how do you attempt to retrieve those results? Could you show any code?

Comment: I want to retrieve them as a list , a list of 50 result

Comment: BTW, that violates Google [ToS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS), namely, item 5.3. I know, that noone cares, but still...

Comment: @Carlo Hye what is this GOOGLE in "Pattern p = Pattern.compile(GOOGLE);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

loop through 5 times, each time adding 10 to the 'start' GET variable in the URL

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ...
    URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.id/search?q=" + newEntry + "&hl=en&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=images&tbs=&start="+(i*10));
    ...
}
```

Comment: Mark it as the answer or +1 it then? :)

Answer (score 0):

Well try going to the next page in the google search results I think each page gives you 10 results

Comment: you change the url parameter for the page

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change the `num` GET parameter in the URL from 10 to 50. This parameter dictates how many results you want shown.